# Is there a way to fix the "Close All" functionality on Eclipse Kepler?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I hope this question is appropriate for Stack Overflow; if not, I apologize. For some reason the close all functionality on my installation of eclipse stopped working. I can still close windows, but I can't close all. Neither the hot key nor the menu functionality works anymore. My theory is that it has something to do with me occasionally breaking source pages out onto other screens. Is there a way to fix this or get some sort of output out of eclipse that will provide some clues?

Comment: Did you check the error log (Windows -> Show View -> Error Log) for exceptions?

Comment: Yeah. Nothing. What's odd is that this started happening in phases. At one point most of the windows would close, now none of the windows close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can try. The first step is the error log (Windows -> Show View -> Error Log).

If you can't see anything in the log, you may try to start Eclipse with `java` instead of `javaw`. Just add

```
-vm
...path-to-java.../java
```

to `eclipse.ini`. Maybe it prints something useful to stdout.

If that also doesn't help, try closing one window manually (for example with <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd>) and then "Close All" again. Repeat until it works. That might give you a clue which window prevents Eclipse from closing everything.

If that doesn't help: You can also close windows by opening the window list (<kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd>). Instead of search, go down once (so the selection is in the list). You can now close windows using <kbd>Delete</kbd> (key repeat works but the UI lags begind).

Comment: Not sure what happened. It more/less fixed itself after closing and opening windows trying to debug it. But this answer does provide some helpful information, so I've mark it as the answer.